# Dynamically swap variables

Tags: vb.net, variables, swap

I'm working in Visual Basic 2010

```
Hitpoints1 -= Player1HandGroup(Number).DamageInteger
```

This is an example line of code in a game I'm designing that removes a given amount of hitpoints from player 1 depending on the item used in the array.

For each player I have different variables. They are
Hitpoints2, Hitpoints3, Hitpoints4, Hitpoints5 respective for each given player.

What I want to do is be able to dynamically change the variable to another variable so I do not have to copy my giant masses of decision logic.

The way the variable will be dynamically changed is via a custom dialog box with Player 1 through Player 5 as the buttons to decide who the player will attack. (I've already made the dialog box)

So if I hit player 2 in the dialog box Hitpoints1 will instead be Hitpoints2.
I'd like to dynamically change the variable, or be able to concatenate  the last letter (numbers 1-5) onto "HitPoints" in the code, in effect being the same as dynamically changing the variable.

One person tried to have me do for each loop...

for n = 1 to 5
HitPoints = HitPoints & n

( your code in here with the HitPoints bit, which will now be HitPoints1)

next n

but that didn't work.

Comment: Make `Hitpoints` an array, instead of separate variables. You can then access `Hitpoints(n)`, where `n` is the player for which you want to modify it.

Comment: Or use a function that returns the new number of hitpoints